# CSS - drop-shadow issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, dropshadow

I'm working with the drop-shadow property. It is working fine in browsers except internet explorer. Its important this works in internet explorer 11 for me. What can I do? Thanks in advance.

```css
.nb-view-project-image {
  max-width: 315px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff4040;
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  -ms-filte: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
}
```

```html
<div class="nb-view-project-image"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe it's the typographical error on -ms-filte: ?

Comment: Hey Jeremiah Cabigting, I edited and tried again. But not working...

Comment: @JeremiahCabigting. It is not to remove, it is to add the "r" at the end, so `-ms-filter`.

Comment: Yeah Jeremiah Cabigting , I edited and tried, but not working..:)

Comment: [`filter`](https://caniuse.com/#search=filter) is not supported in IE11 (that includes `-ms-filter`). Instead use `box-shadow`

Answer (score 1):

Try this css:

```
.nb-view-project-image {
  max-width: 315px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ff4040;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #222;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
-moz-box-shadow: #222 5px 5px 5px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #222;
```

Or:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: #222 5px 5px 5px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #222;
```

Comment: Why would you need `-*-box-shadow` here? `box-shadow` alone is good enough

Comment: Just adds extra support for older browsers

Comment: Ok, but then you should write them before `box-shadow` as they might overwrite it. Always write the property without the prefix last. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use the following code:

```
.nb-view-project-image {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```